# SubReport Issue with Dynamics CRM 2011 Reports using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to add a simple subreport to a report in Reporting Services using Dynamics CRM (FetchXML).  This is all on my local machine, neither report has been published yet.  I am only trying to get them to run in Reporting Services.  I added a Parameter to the subreport for the field "name".  I then added a subreport to the main report.  I then selected the subreport via subreport properties and passed the parameter here as well.

Here is the FetchXML from the Main Report

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="new_databaseserver" />
    <attribute name="new_databasename" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Here is the FetchXML from the subreport

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <attribute name="new_adam" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Here is the error:

[rsErrorExecutingSubreport] An error occurred while executing the subreport 'SubReport1' (Instance: 19iT0R0x0S0): Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'SubReport1', located at: /SubReport1. Please check the log files for more information.

I've been racking my brain over this all weekend.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the log files for more information?

Comment: I don't have access to them at home but I will tomorrow.  Do you see any issue with what I've pasted here so far? Is it possible to use subreports in Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you don't have the filter expression in subreport. I think reporting services tries to get all accounts data from CRM two times: for 1st report and then for subreport. Try use this fetch for subreport:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <attribute name="new_adam" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
       <condition attribute="name" operator="eq" value="@Name" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

The `@Name` is name of your parameter.

Comment: Thank you but this didn't seem to work either.  I added the following

Comment: <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <attribute name="new_adam" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
     <filter type="and">
       <condition attribute="name" operator="eq" value="@prmAccountName" />
    </filter>
  </entity>

Comment: How many account records do you have in CRM? Maybe try to add to parent report count limit: <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" count="10">